# What is the correlation between RadioMedium's maxCommunicationRange parameter and Radio transmitter's power parameter?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

Warm greetings to all

I want to have an understanding of the RadioMedium's parameter: `maxCommunicationRange` and the Radio transmitter's parameter : `power`

Indeed, I wanted my nodes don't communicate with neighbors if those later are beyond a threshold range. I parameterized as follow :

```
*.radioMedium.*.power = -110dBm
*.radioMedium.*.bandwidth = 2.8MHz
*.radioMedium.*.centerFrequency = 2.4GHz
*.radioMedium.*.maxTransmissionPower = 2.24mW
*.radioMedium.*.maxTransmissionDuration = 1000ms
*.radioMedium.*.maxCommunicationRange = 20m

**.radio.transmitter.power = 2.24mW
```

But I'm surprised to see that packets are still transmitted to all the nodes in my network. I even set `*.radioMedium.*.maxCommunicationRange = 0m` but all the nodes still receive packets.

Unlikely, when I variate the transmitter's power parameter (`**.radio.transmitter.power = 0.05mW`), I clearly saw that only the nodes which are at a certain distance around the sender node are receiving the packets. But the problem is that I can't exactly know this admissible distance of communication whereas I need to know it in my work.

1- How does this parameter ( maxCommunicationRange ) work?

2- How can I impose to my nodes not to communicate with each other beyond a certain distance?

3- What is the relationship between `maxCommunicationRange` and `**.radio.transmitter.power`?

I'm using omnetpp-6.0pre11 and INET 4.3

Many thanks for your continued support on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `maxCommunicationRange` is the parameter of the `MediumLimitCache` submodule of `RadioMedium`. The medium limit cache is an optimization, so that the radio medium doesn't have to calculate the ranges with each transmitter/receiver pair from the power and sensitivity, but you can specify some values to use (by default the medium limit cache is not used.) These ranges (max communication and interference range) are used for further optimization, such as the range filter (`rangeFilter` parameter in the radio medium). The filter can be set so that transmissions which are beyond the max communication range are not sent to the nodes.

In your example, if you want the radio medium to not send any transmissions to nodes beyond the max communication range, you also need to set the range filter to communication range (see the radio medium NED documentation).

So by default, the max communication range of the medium limit cache is not used, but the success of a transmission is calculated from the transmitter power, attentuation due to distance and the receiver sensitivity. To set a communication range, the power and sensitivity need to be fine-tuned.

However, you mentioned that it is important for the communication range to be a specific distance. For this, the `UnitDiskRadio` model might be better suited (if you don't care about other things about the transmissions such as  signal attenuation). In this model, you can set specific communication ranges for each transmitter, and transmissions in the range are always successful, out of range they are never.

Comment: Hi, Thank you @aadamgeorge309 for your time and explanation. Everything is so clear for me now, your suggestion as well.

Comment: What is the sample of these sentences? I can't find a real sample. "the success of a transmission is calculated from the transmitter power, attenuation due to distance and the receiver sensitivity. To set a communication range, the power and sensitivity need to be fine-tuned." and "if you want the radio medium to not send any transmissions to nodes beyond the max communication range, you also need to set the range filter to communication range (see the radio medium NED documentation)."

Comment: If you mean you are looking for examples corresponding to these sentences, here are a few showcases that are somewhat relevant:

https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/visualizer/canvas/instrumentfigures/doc/index.html
https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/visualizer/canvas/routingtable/doc/index.html (Dynamic config)
https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/routing/manet/doc/index.html (mainly AODV and DSDV)

These demonstrate the communication range directly. (the range is only specified with the transmitter power though, the sensitivities are left on default).

Comment: Hi, dear @adamgeorge309, I mainly want to have a document and the Omnet++ sample about setting the communication range based on the transmitter power, attenuation due to distance and the receiver sensitivity. None of the above links in your comment doesn't describe the problem. Thanks

Comment: Basically, it's a trial-and-error process right now. Communication range is dependent on these three properties (distance, tx power and rx sensitivity), so can adjust one of them, and see the resulting communication range (either visualized with the blue circle, or just try if the transmissions can be received). Then repeat. The point is, there is no mechanism to specify a communication range in meters, and the other three parameters are set. (although the unit disk radio works like this, as mentioned above.)

Comment: "The point is, there is no mechanism to specify a communication range in meters, and the other three parameters are set.": what I meant here is that the above-mentioned 3 parameters need to be set, and this results in some communication range.